# WebAuth Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'create' on 'CredentialsContainer': cannot convert to dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, webauthn

I'm having an issue using my JSON object in order to trigger a WebAuthn call in Javascript. On the written navigator.credentials.create() function it is expecting a publicKey object to start the initiation process.

Right now I am using JSON.parse to parse a string into an object. After the response string is parsed, I am then passing it to the webAuthn navigator.credentials.create function but I am getting an error of:

**WebAuth Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'create' on 'CredentialsContainer': cannot convert to dictionary.**

what could be the issue? I already parsed it to be an object, where all of the newline characters are removed. How can I get this object to be reconized? Thanks!

**Original response string being passed**

```
"\"publicKey:  {\\n    challenge: new Uint8Array(["testnumbers"]).buffer,\\n    // Relying Party:\\n    rp: {\\n        name: \\\"Test.com\\\",\\n        id: \\\"test.com\\\"\\n    },\\n    // User:\\n    user: {\\n        id: Uint8Array.from(\\\"test\\\", function (c) { return c.charCodeAt(0) }),\\n        name: \\\"test@gmail.com\\\",\\n        displayName: \\\"test@gmail.com\\\"\\n    },\\n    pubKeyCredParams: [\\n        {\\n            type: \\\"public-key\\\",\\n            alg: -7\\n        }\\n,{\\n            type: \\\"public-key\\\",\\n            alg: -257\\n        }\\n\\n    ],\\n    attestation: \\\"none\\\",\\n    timeout: 60000,\\n    excludeCredentials: [],\\n    authenticatorSelection: {\\nuserVerification: \\\"discouraged\\\",\\nauthenticatorAttachment: \\\"cross-platform\\\"\\n}\\n};\\n\\n\""
```

Answer (score 2):

> **tl;dr:** It looks like you `JSON.stringify()`'d a complex JavaScript object, complete with multiple references to `Uint8Array()`...

The first thing that jumps out is the lack of escaped quotes around `"testnumbers"`:

```
"\"publicKey:  {\\n    challenge: new Uint8Array(["testnumbers"]).buffer,\\n
```

An IDE set to JavaScript language mode calls this out right away:

[image]

The quotes need their own `\\\` to match the other quotes in the string.

Additionally the beginning of `publicKey` is escaped, but not the end:

```
"\"publicKey:
```

If you fix those two you can at least `JSON.parse()` the string, but it just becomes a long string:

```
> JSON.parse(foo)
'publicKey:  {\n' +
  '    challenge: new Uint8Array(["testnumbers"]).buffer,\n' +
  '    // Relying Party:\n' +
  '    rp: {\n' +
  '        name: "Test.com",\n' +
  '        id: "test.com"\n' +
  '    },\n' +
  '    // User:\n' +
  '    user: {\n' +
  '        id: Uint8Array.from("test", function (c) { return c.charCodeAt(0) }),\n' +
  '        name: "test@gmail.com",\n' +
  '        displayName: "test@gmail.com"\n' +
  '    },\n' +
  '    pubKeyCredParams: [\n' +
  '        {\n' +
  '            type: "public-key",\n' +
  '            alg: -7\n' +
  '        }\n' +
  ',{\n' +
  '            type: "public-key",\n' +
  '            alg: -257\n' +
  '        }\n' +
  '\n' +
  '    ],\n' +
  '    attestation: "none",\n' +
  '    timeout: 60000,\n' +
  '    excludeCredentials: [],\n' +
  '    authenticatorSelection: {\n' +
  'userVerification: "discouraged",\n' +
  'authenticatorAttachment: "cross-platform"\n' +
  '}\n' +
  '};\n' +
  '\n'
```

And now I'm going to call out the fact that the string contains references to `Uint8Array()` - did you wrap a complex JavaScript object, complete with comments, in quotes and then run it through `JSON.stringify()`? JSON can't contain values like that, it's limited to primitives like strings, numbers, arrays, and objects containing properties with such values. And it may come as a surprise that JSON doesn't support comments either!

If you're generating this code server side intending to transmit it to the front end as JSON to then execute in the browser, you've got the right idea but your execution is in need of refinement.

For starters you need to encode your `Uint8Array`'s into something that can be encoded as a string. Base64 is such an encoding - encode your `challenge` and `user.id` buffer to string, include those strings in your JSON, then convert the strings back to a buffer in the browser (how you accomplish this I'll leave as an exercise to the reader, there are many ways to do so).

And if this string is being sent via a network request then I'd suggest trying to send this code *as JSON* instead, and by that I mean setting `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in the header of whatever responds to the request that returns the string you're trying to transmit over. Let whatever server framework you're using handle the intricacies of sending JSON over the wire and forget about stringifying anything.

Comment: ok that makes sense, the first part was a mistake not to correctly quote the response, but for the second part I cannot change the response on the server side. I would have to deconstruct and then reconstruct everything on the front end, and I am unsure how to do that. @IAmKale

Comment: WebAuthn requires coordination between front end and back end, there's no real way around this. Juggling these values between front end and back end is a known pain point with the API, which has lead to the creation of libraries like https://github.com/github/webauthn-json. I'm also partial to my own combination of JS/TS WebAuthn libraries known as SimpleWebAuthn: https://github.com/MasterKale/SimpleWebAuthn